# Does `/forceload` generate new chunks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm not sure how to test this myself so maybe someone already knows the answer..

Does the `/forceload` command generate new chunks?

If so, I can then use `/forceload` to pre-generate the Minecraft world instead of teleporting players around..

This would be useful for pre-generating UHC maps.

---

Note: You cannot use this command in command blocks. You'd need to write a plugin for your server or write a script that sends commands to your server.

---

Edit: If anyone has come here to find a script to generate chunks, check out https://github.com/davidcallanan/mc-world-pregenerator

Comment: Let's see if I can do this in less than 7 minutes this time…

Comment: 4 minutes this time, including one attempt that failed for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick way to test this:

- Make a new world.
- `/forceload add 1000000 1000000`
- Look in the `region` folder of the world for the file `r.1953.1953.mca`.

Result: The file exists. Therefore, `/forceload` does generate chunks.

---

Some additional information: Chunk generation happens in multiple phases and there are a few rare cases where the generation can stop after one of these phases (like beyond 30M) and some even rarer ones where it can resume from there later (like when pushing blocks into ungenerated chunks and later walking there).
So I checked with NBTExplorer to see what stage of generation those chunks were in and it turned out to even include ores and structures like mineshafts. I did not find any animals, but I'm not sure if they're even supposed to generate out of player range. Villagers for example would probably generate with villages, as well as their farm animals. Also elder guardians, the Ender dragon, shulkers, woodland mansion mobs, etc.

Comment: Wow, thanks for all the quick answers :) I never would have thought to look for the region files. I was going to try to use the new mcedit but it runs too slow on my computer.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion a while ago when trying to see what biome generated at a specific coordinate. Not sure if I was successful or not, but I did learn that forceload generates chunks

Comment: This works much better than having to load a minecraft client and teleport a player around. Unfortunately the forceload command wasn't added until version 1.13.1 and I need it on 1.12.2.